# Fastest way to direct users to different view controllers at the start of an app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

1. The user opens up the app
2. A short server check is going on to see if the user has an account
3. If user has an account go to VC1
4. If user doesn't have an account go to VC2

Where and how is the fastest way to implement this inside my project? (Fastest: loading time, not development time)

Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write down the code directly in the AppDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Or:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
```